# Cannot configure tex-common after failed font installation

Tags: fonts, latex

I tried to install some fonts for my university's corporal design, this failed. Afterwards I removed texlive completely and tried to install it anew (using apt-get), this is not possible since tex-common cannot be configured:

```
sudo dpkg --configure tex-common

Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.tupKRznV
Please include this file if you report a bug.

Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
```

The directory /etc/texmf/updmap.d does not exist on my system.

The log file mentioned reads:

```
sudo more /tmp/updmap.tupKRznV

updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /home/XXX) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

ERROR:  The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
    dinbold.map (in /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
    univers.map (in /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)

    Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

dinbold and univers are the fonts I tried to install. Actually I don't want them anymore, I just gave up on them. I just want a clean, fresh install of texlive. Soemwhere these fonts are still in system, but I can't find where. What shall I do?

Greetings.

Comment: With what command you have it removed?

Comment: It would be useful to know what has been the procedure you used to try to install the local fonts. Something pesky is going on there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably something wrong with the procedure you followed to install the local fonts. There are "local user" tex-related files in `/root`, which is the  *root user*'s home directory --- seems like you tried to do a user-local font installation as root, which is a no-no.

Now, even if you un-installed everything with something like `apt-get remove --purge`, notice that the files in the home directories are never touched by the package system --- even the `/root` ones.

There should be no tex-related things in `/root` --- you are not supposed to run TeX &co as root, really. So try to remove those things (everything tex-related under `/root`) and try again.

Comment: Thanks, your answer finally led to success. There were two folders in /root/ concerning Tex, I deleted both of them and installed texlive again, now it works. 

My university's fonts came with a script to install them, I guess this script created those folders.

Comment: @terri, so probably the script is meant to be run as your user, not as root. --- maybe it failed for that. But double check before; if it messes up your local `$HOME` configuration then it's not easy to go back.